# Which Linux Distro came with all Daily Softwares

Tags: linux, distributions, hardware-compatibility, free-software

I'm new to Linux world and still learning on How to Build personal Linux Distro. And before I can create one, I would like to get as many computers that I can have and install Linux on it. But I need one package for all. A distro that came well with all "Daily Softwares"; Office, Designs software, Chess or puzzle or any game to play with two kids, a full video codec, and run on minimum hardware (Intel Pentium 4 3ghz, 2gb of ram, 60gb IDE/SATA). I don't bother with all the fancy looks on dekstop if it can came in one package that similar to KDE (kubuntu) but lightweight.

> **THE KEY IS**, There is no need any second or third software to download
>   (except the update and upgrade) so I don't involve to any other license (non-free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Debian](https://www.debian.org/) is composed entirely of free software, is well-supported by updates and has a large selection of packages in its default repositories. Debian comes with over 43,000 packages, precompiled software bundled up in a nice format for easy installation on your machine. A Pentium 4, 1GHz system is the minimum recommended for a desktop system.

Many other popular Linux distributions are based on Debian including Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Raspbian.

**Recommended Minimum System Requirements**

```
Install Type    RAM (minimum)   RAM (recommended)   Hard Drive
No desktop      128 megabytes   512 megabytes        2 gigabytes
With Desktop    256 megabytes   1 gigabyte          10 gigabytes
```